# Turtlebot3 package - ROS2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to enlarge my wheel using the physical turtlebot3. I'm learning how robotis made the package by looking at the code, anyone know where is the value 0.087890625[deg] derived or get from? is it the Goal Position?

// 0.087890625[deg] * 3.14159265359 / 180 = 0.001533981f

you can see this in the joint state or odometry.cpp file in opencr code

Thanks ROScommunity in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411528/turtlebot3-package---ros2/) by [n000oob](https://answers.ros.org/users/130069/n000oob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2023-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Googling this specific value `0.087890625` I got [this Arduino forum post](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/28bjy-48-stepper-motor-angle-printing-to-time/919924/4) - it looks like it is connected to the step motor and its number of steps per revolution.

One of the answers from the link:

> 64 steps per revolution (5.625° steps) and 1:64 gearing gives 4096 steps per output shaft revolution (0.087890625° steps).

P.S.
Be a bit careful with enlarging the wheel radius - calculate how much you can enlarge it before the motor gives up.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2023-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1